# FastAPI workers timeout

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

**Some background:**

I am not sure if the following details are required to reply to my question but providing them just for reference. I am developing a FastAPI POST endpoint which does the following:

- Receives an image file (multipart/form-data)
- Converts the file stream to a numpy array.
- Processes the image using open CV and tensorflow

The API is deployed on Google App Engine Flex (1-4 cores, 1-4 workers), using gunicorn and uvicorn. When I am calling an endpoint the average response time is ~1 seconds. However, when I am load testing the API with 5 concurrent users the average response time goes to ~4-5 seconds per request and then some uvicorn workers start to timeout and get killed. As a result I receive 502 responses from the nginx server.

**My question is the following:**

Since the default timeout of uvicorn is 30 seconds, I don't undertand why the workers are being terminated before they require ~30 seconds to respond. I have read that the 30 seconds timeout is not per request. However I do not understand under which circumstances a worker is supposed to timeout. For instance, in case all workers manage to respond within 5-10 seconds, is it normal to see workers timeout while the timeout threshold is 30?

Comment: Hello, did you find the cause of this? I'm also experiencing 502 responses in our app caused by the upstream towards FastAPI/uvicorn.

Comment: May be it is this timeout: https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#timeouts

Comment: Thanks for your respone. I do not think this is the error because I receive 502, not 503. Additionally I have not used this flag, but maybe there is a default value for this parameter.

Comment: @gsach I'm seeing a default timeout of 2 seconds. I had a similar issue that was manageable by using the keep alive flag with 10 seconds. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#keepalive

Comment: If anyone having the issue has a stacktrace, please share it, otherwise it will be hard to troubleshoot

Comment: Gunicorn has a default 30s timeout IIRC, but are you sure Uvicorn does?  As far as I can tell, it doesn't have any timeout...  I mean, I'm not seeing my requests being cut off.